# How to use Core Data to filter data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that fetches data from a webservice and parses it into Core Data.

[image: TabBarDesign]

The app is tabbar based and the first tab, `IntroViewController`, is used for setting preferences. There are 2 options the user can filter stores by:

**Drive Thru** is activated by tapping on a `DriveThru` Cell which sets `self.driveThru = TRUE`.

**Open Now** is activated by tapping on a `Open Now Cell` which sets `self.open = TRUE`.

[image: IntroViewController]

All the data for the locations is stored in the database. At the bottom of the `IntroViewController` is a Search button which takes you to the `tableviewcontroller` tab. This:

1. Populates `self.stores` array from the Core Data fetch
2. Creates `MyLocation` objects WITH `estado` property set to open or closed string
3. Sorts that `MyLocation` array and re-sets that `self.annotationsToSort` array as the sorted one
4. Finally it uses the sorted version to populate the `tableview`

If the user checked the drivethru option in the introviewcontroller then it should present the tableview tab with only those with drivethru.  This works fine.

Now, if he checked the Open Now option in the introviewcontroller then it should only display the stores that are open.

Here is my current tableviewcontroller method to fetch from the db:

```
- (void)loadRecordsFromCoreData {
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self.managedObjectContext reset];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:self.entityName];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                     [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"nombrePublico" ascending:YES]]];
        //Add Predicate
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(driveThru == %@)", [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.driveThru]];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        self.stores = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
    }];
    [self populateLocationsToSort];
}
```

[image: self.stores array with locations]

This will return all stores. So I did this in the `populateLocationsToSort` method when cycling thru the `self.stores` array:

```
for (Location * locationObject in self.stores) {
        // 3. Unload objects values into locals
        NSString * storeDescription = locationObject.nombrePublico;
        NSString * address = locationObject.direccion;
        NSString * hor_LV = locationObject.hor_LV;
        NSString * hrs24 = locationObject.hrs24;
        NSString * driveThru = locationObject.driveThru;
        ...
        NSString * estado;

        // Set it based on TimeComparator
        if ([TimeComparator dealWithTimeStrings2:locationObject.hor_LV]) {
            estado = @"Open";
        } else {
            estado = @"Closed";
        }

        // 4. Create MyLocation object based on locals gotten from Custom Object
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coordinate.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;
        MyLocation *annotation = [[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:storeDescription address:address coordinate:coordinate distance:0 hrs24:hrs24 driveThru:driveThru hor_LV:hor_LV  estado:estado];

        // 5. Calculate distance between locations & uL
        CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:annotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:self.userLocation];
        annotation.distance = calculatedDistance/1000;

        //Add annotation to local NSMArray
        [self.annotationsToSort addObject:annotation];

    }
[self sort];
...
```

So now my `self.annotationsToSort` array contains my Location objects from the database. These objects now contain the `estado` field as either open or closed based on the current time.

But now comes the part where I need to display only the Open stores in the `tableviewcontroller`.  How should I manipulate the data in order to do that?  The only thing I came up with is:

1. Cycle through `self.annotationsToSort` before sorting
2. Create a new array without the objects where `estado = closed`
3. Then sort

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ideally you would filter the open shops already in the fetch request. How to do that depends on how exactly the opening hours are stored in the Location entity.

Comment: The database has a field called horarioLV which contains the string "7:00AM - 10:00PM". I cant parse it inside the database. Also I wouldnt want to store the open or closed state because its something that changes constantly depending on the hour the user uses the app.